# How to identify road geometries across time?

Tags: python, osmnx

I am using osmnx 0.12 to request road networks from OSM.

I want to collect the road network of Amsterdam on a daily basis in order to create a spatio-temporal model.
When I request the road network on two distinct dates, i.e. 1st of January 2020 and 1st of March 2020, I obtain two non-overlapping sets of nodes.
I understand that new nodes may have appeared while others may have been removed.
However, I could not find any way in which this behaviour is tracked. For example, a list of added/removed nodes compared to the previous version of the road network.  Moreover, it looks like there is a set of nodes which have different ids in the two road networks.

**Question**: I would like to identify the road (25596477, 4482759750, 0) from January 1st, 2020, with its equivalent on March 1st, 2020. Is this possible to do, and if so, how?

I attach a code snippet to reproduce this behaviour for the above road segment.

```
import osmnx
import datetime

bbox = (52.36477309990933, 4.897592764542301, 52.369790450504155, 4.912605158495796)
custom_filter = '["area"!~"yes"]' \
            '["highway"!~"cycleway|footway|path|pedestrian|steps|track|corridor|proposed|construction|bridleway|abandoned|platform|raceway"]' \
            '["motor_vehicle"!~"no"]' \
            '["motorcar"!~"no"]' \
            '["access"!~"private"]' \
            '["service"!~"private|emergency_access"]'

dates_to_query = ["20200101", "20200301"]

road_networks = []
modified_road_segments = []
node_of_interest = 25596477

for date_to_query in dates_to_query:
    date_to_query = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_query, "%Y%m%d").isoformat()
    custom_settings = f"""[out:json][timeout:180][date:"{date_to_query}"]"""

    graph = osmnx.graph_from_bbox(north=bbox[2], 
                              south=bbox[0], 
                              west=bbox[1], 
                              east=bbox[3], 
                              custom_settings=custom_settings, 
                              custom_filter=custom_filter)
    nodes, road_network_gdf = osmnx.graph_to_gdfs(graph.to_undirected())

    road_networks.append(road_network_gdf)
    modified_road_segments.append(road_network_gdf[
                                road_network_gdf['u'] == node_of_interest
                                ]
                              )
```

*modified_road_segments* contains two linestrings, on 1st of January and on 1st of March. the v node is updated, however, the two linestrings spatially describe the same road segment.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet in the question itself that allows us to fully reproduce your problem from scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @gboeing, I added a code snippet.